# PHP Mailer SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) but SMTP tester works

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a mail with PHP Mailer from my website using SMTP.

I have the host, username, port, and SSL config all set up but for some reasing it's throwing:

```
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)
```

However, when using the exact same parameters in a testing tool like https://www.smtper.net/ it works and sends the mail correctly.

Any ideas?

EDIT - Code:

```
$smtpHost = "my.host.com";
$smtpUser = "info@mydomain.com";
$smtpPass = "mypass1234";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 587; //Tried with 465 too
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; //Tried with true too
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";

$mail->Host = $smtpHost;
$mail->Username = $smtpUser;
$mail->Password = $smtpPass;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;

$mail->From = $smtpUser;
$mail->FromName = 'Some name';
$mail->AddAddress('someemail@example.com');

$mail->Subject = 'Some subject';
$body = "<h1>Some HTML</h1>";

$mail->Body = $body;

// I tried with and without this part
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$mailSent = $mail->Send();
var_dump($mailSent);
```

Comment: Please post your code (and change host/username to dummy values)

Comment: @freefall Added code!

Answer (score 0):

I'd point you towards two examples from PHPMailer's github:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps - SMTP w/ Authentication (check that your PHP time zone is set, as they mention)

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/ssl_options.phps - Using PHP to adjust the SSL settings if they are incorrect on the mail server